# Facebook dialogs - message parameter

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I know Facebook blocks the message parameter. However, I want users to send a prepared message to their walls. I'm not using the Facebook Android [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit). I use a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to send parameters (name, link, description...) to webview. User selects messages from listview, and I want it to appear on Facebook's `messagebox("Write something...")`. Is it possible to make this in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, I don't think this is possible because Facebook uses an iFrame to prevent JavaScripter code from modifying dialogs (I could be wrong about this, but in my personal attempts it was impossible to modify Facebook dialogs).

However, if your user grants your application permission to post to friends walls, you can design your own dialog and simply use the API to post to your friend's wall.